# Ubuntu 14 dual monitor problem

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors

I have a problem with my ubuntu 14, these are the steps:

1. Put applications on 2 screens.
2. Lock ubuntu.
3. Allow monitors to sleep.
4. Unlock ununtu.

Opened apps are still running but all of them are moved to a single monitor.
Sometimes I can't access any opened app until I lock & unlock ubuntu again.

This problem happened suddenly, I did not changed any setting.
I have 2 Philips 24" monitors, same model.

Comment: What graphics card do you have, and what drivers ?

Comment: integrated video chipset. this problem happened suddenly

Comment: video card: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
driver: configuration: driver=i915 latency=0